# Bookmark words with Google Chrome

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can bookmark words.

If possible:

- free
- when reading the list of bookmarked words, it would be great to have their definition as well along with synonyms, examples of use and pronunciation.
- can bookmarked not just words but phrases too.

I am only interested in English words.

---

My use case: when reading webpages, I sometimes encounter word that I find interesting and would like to remember later on. Right now I copy-paste them into a Google document but this is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2):

This looked like a good first project for me, so I went ahead and made a Chrome extension:

[BookmarkWords](https://github.com/shu8/BookmarkWords/) (I know, creative name - wait till you see the logo ;).

To install it, click on [this](https://github.com/shu8/BookmarkWords/raw/503218374207d861fb0ce4c4733be28d89c0e1b2/wordBookmarkDeleteFunction.crx) link and download the `crx` file. Then, go to `chrome://extensions` on your computer, check `Enable Developer Mode` and drag the `crx` file there.

The instructions on how to use it will open up when you install it, but it's really simple:

- you right click a selection (or press Alt+B)
- click 'bookmark word'

You can change the keyboard shortcut by clicking `Keyboard Shortcuts` at the bottom of `chrome://extensions`.

It works by saving the *selection*, so it can do multiple words / phrases.

I hope to add a definition or a link to the definition soon, but for now, this does what you want!

If there are any good designers out there, I'd be happy if you wanted to create a logo that actually looks good, design a good color scheme, or anything design related! ;p (I'm not the most creative of people :)

You can see the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/shu8/BookmarkWords/) and if you do notice something wrong, or want to fix it, please do :)